# Fast forward time when writing Substrate Runtime Test

Tags: unit-testing, rust, substrate, parity-io

I am writing an auction type application with Substrate runtime. In writing test case, how can I fast forward the blockchain time (what's retrieved from `<timestamp::Module<T>>::get()`) so I can reach the auction closing time and test the closing logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Timestamp::set_timestamp` to change the timestamp to whatever value you want. e.g. `Timestamp::set_timestamp(42);`

You can check the tests for `srml-timestamp` for examples

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fe7f6aff197cd68e102539a42df1134d600b4584/srml/timestamp/src/lib.rs#L368

Comment: Note that this does not trigger any other functions like `on_finalize` or `on_initialize`. You will have to do that manually.

Comment: Tracking issue for fast forward blocks (instead of time): https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/2818

Comment: Additionally, you might need to call `session::rotate_session()` as well.